# Water Edge Detection

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

Is there a robust way to detect the water line, like the edge of a river in this image, in OpenCV?

[image]
<sub>(source: [pequannockriver.org](http://www.pequannockriver.org/pics/river1.JPG))</sub>

Comment: The left bank of the river might be more distinguishable. The presence of shrubs on the left bank add a lot of high-frequency variations, compared to the smooth water surface on the left. The right bank seems challenging, even for a human artist. Regardless, for this type of tasks, an algorithm that works well on one image might work poorly on many other images.

Comment: To improve the question, please describe the motivation or purpose of finding the water line. For example, are you using the water line position in some kind of comparisons? If so, do you intend to compare the results from multiple images taken at different times? These intentions would have been even more challenging. By describing your purpose, we could make suggestions while avoiding approaches that are difficult or impossible.

Comment: I understand it would be difficult to come up with one algorithm that would be robust across a variety of scenes, but in general what kind properties/filters would you use on an image to detect water?

Comment: I need to do some processing with the material near the shoreline, so I wanted to detect the waterline in an image in order to find elements like the shrubs.

Answer (score 1):

This task is challenging because a combination of techniques must be used. Furthermore, for each technique, the numerical parameters may only work correctly for a very narrow range. This means either a human expert must tune them by trial-and-error for each image, or that the technique must be executed many times with many different parameters, in order for the correct result to be selected.

The following outline is highly-specific to this sample image. It might not work with any other images.

***One bit of advice:*** As usual, any multi-step image analysis should always begin with the *most reliable step*, and then proceed down to the less reliable steps. Whenever possible, the less reliable step should make use of the result of more-reliable steps to augment its own accuracy.

### Detection of sky

Convert image to HSV colorspace, and find the cyan located at the upper-half of the image.

Keep this HSV image, becuase it could be handy for the next few steps as well.

### Detection of shrubs

Run Canny edge detection on the grayscale version of image, with suitably chosen sigma and thresholds. This will pick up the branches on the shrubs, which would look like a bunch of noise. Meanwhile, the water surface would be relatively smooth.

Grayscale is used in this technique in order to reduce the influence of reflections on the water surface (the green and yellow reflections from the shrubs). There might be other colorspaces (or preprocessing techniques) more capable of removing that reflection.

### Detection of water ripples from a lower elevation angle viewpoint

Firstly, mark off any image parts that are already classified as shrubs or sky. Since shrub detection would be more reliable than water detection, shrub detection's result should be used to inform the less-reliable water detection.

**Observation**

Because of the low elevation angle viewpoint, the water ripples appear horizontally elongated. In fact, every image feature appears stretched horizontally. This is called [Anisotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropy). We could make use of this tendency to detect them.

*Note: I am not experienced in anisotropy detection. Perhaps you can get better ideas from other people.*

**Idea 1:**

Use [maximally-stable extremal regions (MSER)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) as a blob detector.

The Wikipedia introduction appears intimidating, but it is really related to connected-component algorithms. A naive implementation can be done similar to [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

**Idea 2:**

Notice that the image features are horizontally stretched, a simpler approach is to just sum up the absolute values of horizontal gradients and compare that to the sum of absolute values of vertical gradients.